# Emulating an app with models in a django unittest

Tags: django, unit-testing

I`m writing some code which retrieves info about installed apps, especially defined models, and then does stuff based on that information, but I`m having some problems writing a clean, nice unittest. Is there a way to emulate or add an app in unittests without have to run manage.py startproject, manage.py startapp in my testsfolder to have a test app available for unittests?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow...is it that you want to dynamically install apps during testing, or are you wondering what to do with models/apps needed only for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, try this on for size:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.test.testcases import TestCase
from django.db.models import loading

class AppTestCase(TestCase):
    '''
    Adds apps specified in `self.apps` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and
    performs a `syncdb` at runtime.
    '''

    apps = ()
    _source_installed_apps = ()

    def _pre_setup(self):
        super(AppTestCase, self)._pre_setup()

        if self.apps:
            self._source_installed_apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
            settings.INSTALLED_APPS = settings.INSTALLED_APPS + self.apps
            loading.cache.loaded = False
            call_command('syncdb', verbosity=0)

    def _post_teardown(self):
        super(AppTestCase, self)._post_teardown()

        if self._source_installed_apps:
            settings.INSTALLED_APPS = self._source_installed_apps
            self._source_installed_apps = ()
            loading.cache.loaded = False
```

Your test case would look something like this:

```
class SomeAppTestCase(AppTestCase):

    apps = ('someapp',)
```

In case you were wondering why, I did an override of `_pre_setup()` and `_post_teardown()` so I don't have to bother with calling `super()` in `setUp()` and `tearDown()` in my final test case. Otherwise, this is what I pulled out of Django's test runner. I whipped it up and it worked, although I'm sure that, with closer inspection, you can further optimize it and even avoid calling `syncdb` every time if it won't conflict with future tests.

#### EDIT:

So I seem to have gotten out of my way, thinking you need to dynamically add new models. If you've created an app for testing purposes only, here's what you can do to have it discovered during your tests.

In your project directory, create a `test.py` file that will contain your test settings. It should look something like this:

```
from settings import *

# registers test app for discovery
INSTALLED_APPS += ('path.to.test.app',)
```

You can now run your tests with `python manage.py test --settings=myproject.test` and your app will be in the installed apps.

Comment: That looks very interesting, but I want to define my app, an app defined just for testing some code working with apps, in my unittest and I don`t see how I can do that using your code. When I do apps = ('someapp',) I want someapp to be defined in my unittest so all test code is contained in one file. Anyway, this gave me an idea. Thanks! :-)'

Comment: I've updated the question. I don't think having all of your app code residing in your `tests.py` is necessarily a good idea. Create a new app that will be in the `INSTALLED_APPS` only for the test environment. If you want to make it clear that it's a test app, perhaps you can convert `tests.py` into a package `tests`, move the tests to `__init__.py` and create another subpackage called `tests.app` and then add `someapp.tests.app` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your test settings.